# CSS Div content not expanding

Tags: css

I have a main div id called #main and then a list ul li...

Here is the css:

```
#main {
  display:block;
}

#main ul {
list-style: none outside none;
margin: 0 0 20px;
padding: 0;
}
```

etc...

The problem is that when the content grows I get the issue shown on the attached image:

[image]

Comment: Fixed height? Floated elements? Positioned Elements?

Comment: We probably need more css there. How is defined the height ? How is overflow set ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `overflow: auto;` in your `main`

```
#main {
  display:block;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: This will fix the issue, however I feel that he wants the div to grow based on content rather than overflow.

Comment: @RyanMcDonough I'd have thought that would happen with overflow:auto, why not?

Comment: Overflow allows you to add a scrollbar to the div, so you can scroll content. Useful for when you have a set height or width div and content that could be larger. It doesn't increase the height or width though. Sorry I can't see the image due to a firewall, but just for awareness overflow:auto does scroll, but doesn't increase the div size.